# Don't want Logged in user to change any files

Tags: windows-7, security

We have a PC that we are setting up for a client, and the client wants us to lock down the PC as much as possible.  I have a user called UserA that is the user that AutoLogs into the system.  This user needs to be able to run a web page, and that is all.

I have looked at file permissions and I see the in the C:\Users folder UserA had full control of its profile folder.  Is there any way to remove that without causing the system to not run?

Basically I want UserA to login and be able to run IE, but not make any file/folder changes.  I would do Windows Embedded but I am running out of time.  So I am hoping there is someway to do this on the full version of windows.

Thanks.

Comment: There are numerous software packages that allow you to freeze a HDD but it's not possible for a user not to have full control of its user profile

Comment: See if application whitelisting helps:http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/

Comment: Have you looked at kiosk mode?

Answer (score 0):

[Deep Freeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_%28software%29) plus automatic periodic reboots is a common software solution to this problem.